# Trouble implementing a SOFM (Self Organizing Feature Map)

Tags: plotting

I have been given some Mathematica code to use to implement a 3x3 SOFM and see how it changes when I alter 2 variables, lambda and gamma. This is my first time using mathematica so I am a bit confused as to how to proceed. I initially thought I could replace n with 3, and lamba and gamma with arbitrary values to be changed later but I can't get the program to return anything with Shift+Enter, and Mathematica doesn't seem to give any error feedback.

Thank you for your time, any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code is :

```
(*Initialise a random array of points*)
start[n_]:=Table[{Random[],Random[]},{i,n},{j,n}];

(*Update using 4-neighbours of nearest point on this iteration*)
(*Points selected uniformly from unit square*)
(*learning coefficients lamda and gamma*)
update[state_,lamda_,gamma_]:=Module[{a,b,c,n},
n=Length[state];

(*Pick a new input point at random*)
a={Random[],Random[]};

(*Find the nearest unit*)
b=Table[(state[[i,j]]-a).(state[[i,j]]-a),{i,n},{j,n}];
c=Position[b,Min[b]][[1]];

(*Update it and its neighbours*)
b=state;
b[[c[[1]],c[[2]]]]+=lamda(a-b[[c[[1]],c[[2]]]]);
If[c[[1]]>1,b[[c[[1]]-1,c[[2]]]]+=gamma*(a-b[[c[[1]]-1,c[[2]]]])];
If[c[[1]]<n,b[[c[[1]]+1,c[[2]]]]+=gamma*(a-b[[c[[1]]+1,c[[2]]]])];
If[c[[2]]>1,b[[c[[1]],c[[2]]-1]]+=gamma*(a-b[[c[[1]],c[[2]]-1]])];
If[c[[2]]<n,b[[c[[1]],c[[2]]+1]]+=gamma*(a-b[[c[[1]],c[[2]]+1]])];
(*Return the new state*)
b]

(*Simplified graph plotter for 1-d arrays*)
(*Can be used for plotting convergence statistics*)
plotlist[list_]:=ListPlot[list,PlotRange->All,PlotJoined->True]

(*and in 2-d as an image*)
plotim[image_]:=ListDensityPlot[image,Mesh->False,PlotRange->All, FrameTicks->None]

(*Plot 2-d array for Kohonen net as grid of lines*)
plotgrid[state_]:=Module[{a,n},
    n=Length[state];
    a={};
    Do[a=Append[a,Line[{state[[i,j]],state[[i+1,j]]}]],{i,n-1},{j,n}];
    Do[a=Append[a,Line[{state[[i,j]],state[[i,j+1]]}]],{i,n},{j,n-1}];
    Show[Graphics[a]]]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: This time I formatted the code for you. Please learn how do it by yourself.

Comment: Function definitions (as posted)  usually will not return anything per se. You will need to call them with some arguments. You should probably start with some *Mathematica* tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but may give you sum feel for the use of these functions, which (as @YvesKlett commented) must be called to produce results:

```
z = start[3]
```

produces what I assume to be an initial value for `state`

```
{{{0.068054, 0.872746}, {0.138288, 0.132835}, {0.961732, 
   0.929391}}, {{0.396919, 0.459618}, {0.259304, 0.391254}, {0.690301,
    0.404766}}, {{0.166664, 0.0157626}, {0.964609, 0.947595}, {0.261209, 0.900551}}}
```

Similarly, with `lamda` and `gamma` chosen arbitrarily to be unity,

```
zz = update[z, 1, 1]
```

produces a new expression for (I assume) `state`

```
{{{0.270854, 0.545555}, {0.138288, 0.132835}, {0.961732, 
   0.929391}}, {{0.270854, 0.545555}, {0.270854, 0.545555}, {0.690301,
    0.404766}}, {{0.270854, 0.545555}, {0.964609, 0.947595}, {0.261209, 0.900551}}}
```

Then (with the obsolete `PlotJoined` replaced by `Joined` in `plotlist`)

```
plotgrid[z]
```

[image: plotgrid]

```
plotlist[z]
```

[image: plotlist]

```
plotim[z]
```

[image: plotim]

I regret that I cannot tell you how to interpret these figures.

Answer (score 1):

Up-front, I don't think my answer will really help you because it seems you are *really* new to *Mathematica*. What you teacher/friend gave you are function definitions$^1$. To see something, you need to call them. Let us first note what the single functions do:

- `start[n_]` is just a way to initialize a random nxn SOM
- `update[state_, lambda_, gamma_]` takes a SOM as `state` and does exactly one update step with the parameters `lambda` and `gamma`.
- `plot..` functions are various ways to plot the SOM.

What you can do to investigate in the behavior of a SOM is dynamically plot the grid. With this, you see how fast the SOM is changing:

```
som = start[5];
Dynamic[
 som = update[som, .1, .1];
 Show[plotgrid[som], PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
 ]
```

> [image]

$^1$Please note that this is not a very efficient implementation and I'm pretty sure you will reach its limits on real world problems.